# iPhone alike sliding header, or: how to force immediate redraw on top margin change?

Tags: android-layout, android

I am trying to implement a similar effect like the iPhone-alike sliding header in the iPhone contact app (the sliding header that group the contacts by it's starting letter).

This is the screen of my app, and what I want to achieve is the following:

[image]

I have a 'guide header' and three 'tabs' for sorting the list. When the user scrolls the list up, I want everything to scroll up (guide header, tabs, list). However, when the tabs reach the top of the screen (and the guide header will just be gone off the screen), I want the tabs to stop and stay there (remain as "sticky header"), and only the list items scroll as in any regular list view.

I have a view group (guide header) above a list view.

First of all, I want to have the guide header adjust it's position depending on the scrolling position of the list view.

**First approach:**
My idea was to set an onScrollListener to the list view and change the top margin of the guide header to whatever the scroll position of the first item in the list view is (which would be a negative value).

The logic is correct, but **the problem I'm facing** is that the guide header view doesn't get redrawn fast enough while I'm scrolling in the list view. The guide header view only updates (to my changed top margin value) when the list view fling comes to an end. Even slow scrolling doesn't work. Invalidating (invalidate()) the guide header view or it's parent also doesn't help, since it would just put an invalidation request to the queue, but the invalidation and redrawing doesn't happen immediately, but only when the UI thread becomes idle, which doesn't seem to happen while the user still has his fingers on the scroll list view. Seems that flinging the list view blocks the whole UI thread or keeps it busy for itself.

So the main problem is: changing the margin of the guide header view doesn't become visible immediately while the user is scrolling the list view. The code I'm using it this:

```
@Override
public void onScroll(final AbsListView view, final int firstVisibleItem,
    final int visibleItemCount, final int totalItemCount) {

    // Get the first list item and check it's scroll position. This will be the value (top), that we also
    // use the scroll the header parallel.
    View v = mainList.getChildAt(0);
    final int top = (v==null)?0:v.getTop();

    // This logs the current scroll position of the first list item element/view group.
    Log.d("onScroll", "onScroll: " + top);

    // Here we finally change the margin (setting a negative margin) to the header element.
    ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams)(findViewById(R.id.header_container).getLayoutParams())).setMargins(0, top, 0, 0);

    // was just a test: invalidating the outer container/view group, doesn't help
    // findViewById(R.id.ll_container).invalidate();  
}
```

I do see the "onScroll:" log output I inserted in the code above in the logcat, but the following adjustment of the top margin just doesn't become visible.

**My second approach:** is to use a scrollview for the guide header + tabs and work with those. Scrolling the guide header (which is then a scroll view) from code with scrollView.scrollTo(0,Math.abs(Math.abs(top)) from the onScroll method of the list view does work and almost immediately shows on the screen, however, it's not very accurate/stable when the user flings the list view very fast - meaning it jumps in intervals and doesn't look smooth; it's only accurate/stable when scrolling slowly.

**My question is now:** is there any best practice to accomplish such a sliding header effect, and more concrete: is there a way to force the guide header view to be redrawn while the user is still scrolling the list view (in my first mentioned approach).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you should use some tricks (afaik there is no ready-to-use implementation of such a feature).
For instance, you could detect gestures on your view, and

- if the current gesture matches a
  scroll down, and the first list item
  is visible, animate-shrink the
  header's size to 0, the tab view's
  size to match_parent. Start scrolling
  the list only when the header is not
  present anymore.
- if the current gesture matches scroll
  up, and the first is already visible,
  animate-expand the header to it's
  original size.

So using Animation on the header view might be your solution.

**Update**
An other workaround would be to extend your `List` (the value array of your adapter): 
Inster a new (dummy) item at the top for the header representation, and modify your `ListAdapter`'s `getView` method:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    if (position == 0)
    {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sliding_header, parent, 
            false);
        return convertView;
    }
    //TODO: your original method body comes here
}
```

where the xml referenced by `R.layout.sliding_header` should contain the header layout of your list.

A custom `OnScrollListener` implementation applied to the `ListView` would make unnoticeable that the header actually is an item of the list, since it would hide the scrollbar. 
You should add this listener to your `listView` in the activity's `onCreate` method:

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new MyScrollListener());
```

where `MyScrollListener` is:

```
/**
 * Custom OnScrollListener
 */
private final class MyScrollListener implements OnScrollListener
{
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState)
    {}

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, 
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)
    {
        if (view.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0)
            view.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        else if (!view.isVerticalScrollBarEnabled())
            view.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, there's definitely no out-of-the-box component in that for Android. I was hoping that somebody has developed such as an open source project maybe already, but haven't found anything. About your proposal: I also thought about animations in the beginning but dropped the idea again, because if the user flings the list, I'd need to start like a couple of animations at the same time, actually for every pixel position change of the list. "animate-shrink the header's size to 0" and "animate-expand the header to it's original size": I don't think it will give me the wished effect, ...

Comment: ... the animation-shrink final position should depend on the current scrolling position of the list view. For example, if I have scrolled the first list element only half way up (half of it's height I mean by that), then the guide header shall also only scroll by that amount (of pixels), not entirely animate up yet. But maybe I will look into the animations approach again, to see if it general works better than a margin change regarding UI thread blocking of the list view fling. I just fear that the animation will only start after the fling of the list view is over, not during it. Will see.

Comment: I will also need to cancel any running animations if I'm starting a new one due to changed scrolling position of the list view. Sounds pretty messy, but I will give it a try.

Comment: I've kept trying to solve this in a less painful /resource-consuming way, and in the update I've posted a new workaround (no explicit animations used), which might work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your update, however I followed your hint with the animations, setting the animation to a duration of 0. Animations work fine even while user is flining the lists, so it seems animations aren't that "blocked" but the UI thread. So now I ended up wrapping my guide, tab and list into a framelayout (all starting at the top), and animating guide and tabs in the onScroll listener of the list. UX is more-less acceptable, fine tuning it now. I will vote up your answer for the animations hint.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also try and use my ExpandAnimation for that.
http://udinic.wordpress.com/2011/09/03/expanding-listview-items/

Just pass the animation class that "guide header" view, and let the animation do the work for you, no scrolling is needed in that case, and it's smooth.